# Model inheritance using functional programming style data types

Tags: inheritance, f#, functional-programming, types

I've been using F# recently and tried to code in a functional way rather than doing OOP all over again in a different syntax. I've now run into a problem that I could solve with a mix of inheritance and discriminated unions but for which I'm trying to find a pure functional style representation.

What I want to model is something like this (changed to preserve the pattern since I can't use the actual code):

```
type Shape =
    | Rectangle of Size * Size
    | Circle of Diameter
```

so far so good, but now I need to represent a collection of additional properties relevant for the different types of shapes, like:

```
type ShapeProperty =
    | Color of Shape * Color // Fine, valid for all shapes
    | Rotation of Shape * Angle // Wants to be Rotation of Rectangle * Angle
    | Details of Shape * int // Wants to be Detail of Circle * int
```

If instead of using a discriminated union for Shape, I'd used a base class and inheritance, I could refer to the actual types and make sure Rotation could only be applied to Rectangle and not Circle, but now I can't. Is there a way of implementing something like that while still keeping to pure functional data structures?

**Edit:**

My current solution is to separate the definition of a individual shapes from the fact that shapes are at all related, like this:

```
type Rectangle = Rectangle of Size * Size // Or using a record type
type Circle = Circle of Diameter // Or using a record type
type Shape = RectangleShape of Rectangle | CircleShape of Circle
```

which means that I then have type to refer to in ShapeProperty:

```
type ShapeProperty =
    | Color of Shape * Color
    | Rotation of Rectangle * Angle
    | Details of Circle * int
```

This feels a bit clumsy as now need to encapsulate each shape in the Shape type to store them in a collection, but it does give me a way of expressing the type safety I'm after. Any improvements on this would be welcome.

Comment: How do you plan to use the ShapeProperty type? I think you need a different design here, but it is hard to say what type of design is appropriate without more details.

Comment: I need ShapeProperty (and other classes similar to it) to add properties of various shapes without having to touch the definition of the shapes themselves as in my real case the properties are only relevant when the shapes are used in certain contexts but not all others. Basically I need a type safe representation that lets me do transformations and queries such as "find all shapes that have a rotation of 10".

Comment: What does that mean?  Do circles have a rotation less than 10?  (Circles don't have the concept of rotation the way you described it.)  I think you need more detail about precisely what it is you want.

Comment: The example is definitely not perfect, what I meant by finding all shapes that have a rotation of 10 was performing a search over a collection of ShapeProperty items, selecting each property (and from that each shape) of the expected type and with the expected value. In my example, circles do not have a rotation because rotating a circle (around its center) doesn't change it, in the real code the properties are more obviously not applicable at all if the type doesn't support a "shape".

Comment: first of, rotating a circle around the center might change it, but I am guessing that's a flaw of the example, so I will just ignore it. Secondly as someone who has tried to do what you are trying to do, I can tell you it's a bad idea. A property of a discriminated union must be true for all of the tags(this is a variant of LSP) otherwise they don't belong together in the same union. I will warn you, when I did it the way you came up with, I was fighting the type system(a rectangle is a rectangleshape, let me pass it as a parameter without boxing).

Comment: maybe not the best suggestion, but remove "shape" and add an element into the Shape property for both of the rectangle and circle shapes, rather than discussing their union. This removes both some boxing problems and a layer of abstraction, without adding a particularly large amount of code. The question I would have is, "are there a lot of properties that are true about the union of all shapes, or are there a large number of properties that are disparate from both, as another option is on an invalid match you could choose to fail(violating some type safety, but ideal vs. practical and whatnot

Answer (score 9):

I think discriminated unions may simply be the wrong tool for parts of this job. Just because you are writing functional code doesn't mean you should throw out everything you know.

Discriminated unions are (in some ways, and there is kind of a caveat to this) the inverse of inheritance(derived types), we could call them composed types.

In derived type models everything about the parent is guaranteed to be true about the children(LSP), in this composed type model everything about the children is guaranteed to be true about the parent.(i.e. instead of "new dog : animal, new cat : animal, it's new Dog, Cat : CatDog, so you get a new construction of all statements that are true about cats AND dogs. Think of it as the intersection of all statements about both cat and dog.)

So the question then becomes, "how do we work with derived types in OCaml?" Well, the "O" in there does stand for object...

I would suggest you create an object model with derived types for your shape heiarchy, as you have a top type(shape) and a bottom type(the empty shape,or null). And then you compose your ADT's out of those objects, so you have

abstract Shape ,
Circle : Shape,
Rectangle : Shape,

Then you have

type ShapeProperty =
    | Foo of Shape
    | Bar of Rectangle
    | Blah of Circle;;

Anything that knows about a shape property has to be able to handle all three of those cases(reasonable since that's what you have it for), and circle and rectangle are assignment compatible to shape, so you don't have to worry about boxing conventions.

For what it's worth, YMMV etc. Haskell (the other major ML dialect running around) doesn't use objects for derived types, it uses what are known as "type classes" which are collections of properties/behaviors that you "derive from" and "guarantee an implementation of" thereby allowing a function to take in a concrete instance of a type class.

While much more functional in it's philosophy, trying to figure out what's going on gives me a headache since the conventional abstractions I use for object like constructions no longer apply, and I have to use these constructions that are logically equivalent, but semantically substantially more unusual(although I know a lot of people who use them to great success, so it might just be my own failings).

Note on the caveat, since tagged unions are tagged, all you have to do is guarantee a semantic action for all tags. That action could be "failwith 'why are you giving me one of those, I have no idea what to do with it'". The problem as you noticed with this construction is that you lose a lot of the really cool aspects of type safety in doing so. For example, you write a function that takes in an option int, and then if the option is nothing you throw an exception, well, why did you say you knew how to handle an option int?